# Save backbone model to php

Tags: php, mysql, backbone.js

I'm trying to save a very simple **backbone** model and parse it in a **php** file so it can then be sent to a **MySQL** database. 
Problem is my **php** script stops on "*file_get_contents('php://input')*", and i think it's not returning any data. Another strange thing is in chrome developer tools, in "*Network*", the request method is a **GET**, shouldn't it be a **POST/PUT**?

**model.js** *(Very simple model)*:

```
    Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: "js/php/action.php",

        defaults: {
            name: 'Validation Book',
            author: 'Validation',
            year: '2014'
        }

    });

    var book = new Book();
    book.save();
```

**action.php** (*Kept only what's important, in my code i have so much commented blocks of stuff i tryed already..*):

```
<?php 
    include('connection.php');

    $book_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
    or die("<br> Data not received");

    print_r($book_data);

    $Name = $book_data['name'];
    $Author = $book_data['author'];
    $Year = $book_data['year'];

    mysql_select_db('testdb',$con) or die("Database not selected");
    echo "<br> Table Selected";


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO books(id, name, author, year)
                VALUES('', '$Name', '$Author', '$Year') ") 
    or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<br> Data inserted";

?>
```

1. I'm getting the "Data not received" error from
   "file_get_contents('php://input')".
2. The request method is a GET, accordingly to chrome dev.

So, anything wrong at a first glance?

**UPDATE**

Forget it, its working... I was running the php file in my localhost, instead of the index.html page that actualy triggers the model.js to fire the POST request, that's wy the "file_get_contents" wans't "Geting" anything. It's all good, data is being inserted in my Database! Srry for noobness... I was getting really crazy about this. Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: have just tried your code with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/6dCLf/3/) and it sends POST request for me

Comment: Forget it, its working... I was running the php file in my localhost, instead of the index.html page that actualy triggers the model.js to fire the POST request, that's wy the "*file_get_contents*" wans't "Geting" anything. It's all good, data is being inserted in my Database! Srry for noobness... I was getting really crazy about this. Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Youre right, backbone save function on models without an id should be triggering a POST request (PUT request if an id is already present).

Try this on the controller and see what happens:

`$book_data = $_POST;`

Comment: Tried it, this is the result: "Array()"